# How to run a pytorch model on the browser?

Tags: javascript, python, web-applications, onnx

I would like to know what are the options I have to run an object detection model in the browser, until now I have found the next options:

1. Streamlit: is very simple but requires the server resources to run,
   including its own camera. Besides, I believe is not possible to be
   implemented as a website.
2. Brython: is a JS substitute? I couldnt find the way how to load
   pytorch or libraries.
3. Onnx: Seems to be a very good option, however I dont quite
   understand how to run the model in JS, since I have been using
   python and pytorch only, What is the learning roadmap? What is the
   relation with Webassembly?
4. NCNN: This is the method I know the least, It seems to be able to
   work on basically any device, Webassembly, windows, android..., but
   again, I cant understand how to use my python-pytorch model to this
   framework since I dont know the roadmap.

Are there other options?

Answer (score 1):

There's [TensorFlow.js](https://www.tensorflow.org/js).

You still need to convert your model with something like ONNX, though.

Answer (score 0):

Just to update you.
Tensorflow.js is suitable for the TensorFlow model while onnx runtime web is a good option for others. Things to do are;

- Convert your model to onnx(see PyTorch export onnx)
- Use onnxruntime web to use generated onnx with javascript(detailed at onnxruntime.ai)

If anyone knows more options, kindly add.